# CouchDb sort posts by a user in descending timestamp order

Tags: couchdb

I have posts that have fields like username (author of the post) and timestamp (uploaded time). I am struggling to create a view, which when queried on, grabs posts by a particular user in descending order of the timestamp.

```
map: function(doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'post'){
        emit(doc.username, [doc._id, doc.timestamp]);
    };
},
```

I can query documents authored by a particular user but how do I apply descending = true only on the timestamp field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With CouchDB views, **only the key** can determine the sort order for the index. The value does not factor into sorting/grouping at all.

Thus, if you want to have a view that outputs posts by a user in order of creation (ascending or descending), you'll emit an array as a sort of "composite key". I would highly recommend reading through the [Guide to Views](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/intro.html) in the CouchDB documentation.

For your example, I would make a map function like this:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === 'post') {
    emit([ doc.username, doc.timestamp ]);
  }
}
```

Then, you can get the posts for a specific user with a query like:

```
?start_key=["username"]&end_key=["username","\ufff0"]
```

Which will find the posts for the given "username" ordered by the timestamp ascending. To reverse the ordering, use the following query instead:

```
?start_key=["username","\ufff0"]&end_key=["username"]&descending=true
```

Note that the values for `start_key` and `end_key` have swapped, and `descending=true` has been added.

As mentioned before, read through their documentation as it's an excellent way to wrap your head around the best way to use CouchDB views.