# How to order a Cloudant view by date desc

Tags: nosql, cloudant

I would like to order a Cloudant view by date in descending order, and I'm new to NoSQL and I have no ideia how.

This is what I have so far:

```
function(doc){
  if(doc['type'] == 'DOCUMENT' && doc.date){ 
    emit(doc.date);
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463629/couchdb-sort-posts-by-a-user-in-descending-timestamp-order

Answer (score 0):

When doing your query, specify descending=true

```
curl "https://$ACCOUNT.cloudant.com/$DATABASE/_design/$DDOC/_view/view_name? descending=true" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant/api?topic=cloudant-using-views#query-arguments-using_views

Comment: I can't do that, considering I'm using the conn.search() method from com.cloudant.client.api.Database class

Comment: If that is the case, why don't you use Search.sort: https://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.0.0/com/cloudant/client/api/Search.html#sort-java.lang.String-